# jQuery Validation handling of trailing whitespace with StringLength attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

**Scenario**
My use case is jQuery unobtrusive validation coupled with [the StringLength attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.stringlengthattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). My database column is a varchar(500) and I want to prevent the user from entering more than 500 characters, thus I have the viewmodel property decorated with `[StringLength(500)]`. Very basic.

The html produced for the property is correct:

```
<textarea name="MyTextbox" id="MyTextbox" 
 data-val-required="The MyTextbox field is required." 
 data-val-length-max="500"
 data-val-length="The field MyTextbox must be a string
 with a maximum length of 500." data-val="true"></textarea>
```

**Problem**
 jQuery validation doesn't seem to be considering trailing spaces like it should, and so it's letting bad data through.

For example; if I try to enter the following, these are the results I get:

- 500 characters:
   jQuery validation deems it valid, working as intended.
- 501 characters ***without*** trailing space (ie; string ends in an actual character):
   jQuery validation displays an error like it should, again, working as intended.
- 501 characters ***with*** trailing space (ie; string ends in a space):
   jQuery validation doesn't catch it. It deems it valid and lets it through.

If I don't use server-side validation & it makes it through to DbContext.SaveChanges(), Entity Framework will throw a DbEntityValidationException.
It's not that big of a deal since I do use server-side validation (typical asp.net-mvc check for ModelState.IsValid) and that catches it as invalid. So it won't slip through, but it's a little ugly that it has to hit the server only in this very specific scenario. Is this a bug with jQuery, or is it working as intended? If so, it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: jQuery Validate is working as intended.  It's strange to me that anything would count trailing spaces as valid characters.

Comment: It's not so strange if you consider that the database counts them, which it does for varchar.

Comment: Just to be sure, I setup a demo of the `maxlength` method to confirm my original comment.  Indeed, trailing spaces are ignored.  Perhaps you should file a bug report on the developer's GitHub page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sparky suggested, I submitted it as an issue via the jquery-validation GitHub page, and the author has implemented the change (which can be seen [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/452b823c86a1a106f40625e75323cc8d68395207).)

Comment: So people don't have to look it up: this is fixed since jQuery Validation v1.13.1. Or if an upgrade is not an option, just changing the jquery.validate.js manually by removing the `$.trim()` around `value` (see the linked commit in the answer above) also works.